# Failed to enable unit: Unit file gdm.service does not exist

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

ive been trying to install gnome on my arch linux arm laptop, so i followed all the steps i found on this webpage https://phoenixnap.com/kb/arch-linux-gnome.
Then when i get to step 4 (Start and Enable gdm.service), i fill in the commands
`sudo systemctl start gdm.service`
and
`sudo systemctl enable gdm.service`
and both of these give me an error like this:
`failed to start/enable unit: Unit file gdm.service does not exist.
I have tried a bunch of things, but thye all dont work.
I have also tried to use KDE plasma, but with that i get the same errors except with sddm.service.

i would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

gdm is a part of gnome group, it should be installed as dependency.

In your case, gdm isn't installed correctly, try to reinstall it:

```
sudo pacman -Syyuu
sudo pacman -S gdm
sudo systemctl enable gdm.service
sudo systemctl start gdm.service
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering, i tried your solution yesterday, but sadly it didnt work. but since i wasnt that far into setting up arch yet, i decided to just redo the entire process and thankfully it worked that time. Many thanks!